# Nested dictionary object not found

Tags: vba, dictionary, ms-access

I am attempting to take some table, a list of fields to group by, and a number field as input, to produce an output table that contains the group-by fields and medians for the number field.

I have this working for a single field to group by, but not multiple fields.

I am using nested dictionaries to eventually aggregate my grouped-field values and their medians.

When I try to access the inner dictionary I get a

> '424' Run-time error: Object required

Once I put the inner dictionary in the outer dictionary I cannot access it like one would suspect.

```
Public Sub MedianByGroups(ByVal inputTable As String, ByVal strField As String, _
ByVal strGroup As String, ByVal outputTable As String, _
Optional ByVal strCriteria As String)

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    Dim db As DAO.Database: Set db = CurrentDb()
    Dim rstDomain As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim varMedian As Long: varMedian = 0
    Dim intRecords As Long
    Dim splitgroup As Variant

    splitgroup = Split(strGroup, ", ")

    strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT " & strGroup & " INTO TMP_GROUPINGTABLE FROM " & _
    inputTable & ";"

    DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

    Set rstDomain = db.OpenRecordset("TMP_GROUPINGTABLE")

    Dim i As Integer: i = 0

    Dim group_dict As New Dictionary
    Dim tmp_dict As Dictionary
    Set tmp_dict = New Dictionary

    If Not (rstDomain.EOF And rstDomain.BOF) Then
        rstDomain.MoveFirst
        Do Until rstDomain.EOF = True
            For Each Label In splitgroup
                tmp_dict.Add Label, rstDomain.Fields(Label).Value
            Next Label

            group_dict.Add i, tmp_dct
            Set tmp_dict = New Dictionary
            i = i + 1
            rstDomain.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If

    rstDomain.Close

    For Each key In group_dict.Keys
        For Each addlKey In group_dict(key).Keys
            Debug.Print addlKey, group_dict(key)(addlKey)
        Next addlKey
    Next key

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
end sub
```

If one had a table, called "MYTABLE", that looked like this:

```
GROUP1    GROUP2    VAL1
A         C         400
B         D         500
```

One would call this sub like:

```
call MedianByGroups("MYTABLE", "VAL1', "GROUP1, GROUP2", "OUTPUTTABLE")
```

This doesn't do the Median or any other parts yet, as I am hitting this stumbling point with the dictionaries.

Where it fails is the inner for loop on that nested for loop near the end.

```
For Each addlKey In group_dict(key).Keys
```

Edit: As ComputerVersteher pointed out, the issue was a spelling mistake I had made. The solution to avoid this as Andre mentioned is to add the [option explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/bw9t3484(v=vs.84)) to the module.

Comment: `tmp_dict.Add Label, rstDomain.Fields(Label)` - have not looked hard at this but do you mean to add the `Field` object to the dictionary here?  It's not safe to rely on default properties (if you do really mean to add  Value then it's best to be explicit about that)

Comment: I see what you mean, and no I did not mean to add the object but rather the value. Thanks for pointing that out I'll update the main question. Although it is still having the same issue

Comment: There is a typo in `group_dict.Add i, tmp_dct` and many missing declarations, what shows a missing`OPTION EXPLICIT`on top of every module! Code works for me if typo corrected and vars declared.

Comment: This should be a Function that returns an array or recordset with the data. That can be stored in a table if needed. Get rid of`DoCmd.SetWarnings False` (never turn of error-msgs in whole code) and dont use`DoCmd`if there are alternatives (one exeption`DoCmd:OpenForm/Report`). `db.Execute`is the better option instead of`DoCmd.RunSQL`.  No need for`TMP_GROUPINGTABLE`, just create a rs with `SELECT DISTINCT " & strGroup & " FROM " & _
    inputTable`.

Comment: This can't be stressed enough. Put [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) at the top of each module. 
It enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared or misspelled variables/constants at compile time. 
To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor. 
This is really a must have for VBA development.

Answer (score 2):

***Not a complete answer*** -- I set up an example without the MS Access-specific parts and the logic in your code seems to run fine. As near as I can tell, there's no real difference in the logic below and your code above. Does this example run for you?

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestingNestedDictionaries()
    Dim group_dict As New Dictionary
    Dim tmp_dict As Dictionary
    Set tmp_dict = New Dictionary

    Dim labels As Variant
    labels = Array("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 5
        Dim label As Variant
        For Each label In labels
            tmp_dict.Add label, label & "-" & i
        Next label
        group_dict.Add i, tmp_dict
        Set tmp_dict = New Dictionary
    Next i

    '--- pull out one color
'    Const THIS_COLOR As String = "green"
'    Dim group As Variant
'    For Each group In group_dict
'        Dim subDict As Dictionary
'        Set subDict = group_dict(group)
'        Debug.Print subDict(THIS_COLOR)
'    Next group

    Dim key As Variant
    Dim addlKey As Variant
    For Each key In group_dict.Keys
        For Each addlKey In group_dict(key).Keys
            Debug.Print addlKey, group_dict(key)(addlKey)
        Next addlKey
    Next key

End Sub
```

Comment: This does run fine for me. I'm not sure what could be causing my problem, but it must be something to do with pulling from a table.

Comment: Try editing your own code to add static values to the dictionaries instead of pulling from a table. Just work it back from anything specific to Access until it works, then start putting it back in again one at a time. You'll be able to bracket the problem and find it then.

Comment: @Jsqsh Typo in your code`group_dict.Add i, tmp_dct`instead of` `group_dict.Add i, tmp_dict`(you miss an **i** in tmp_d**i**ct). Use`OPTION EXPLICT`!.

Comment: Wow, that was my problem. The `option explicit` would've helped me to not embarrass myself by asking this question because of a typo. Thank you. I'm not sure if I should remove this question somehow or if it will somehow be helpful to others.

Comment: @Jsqsh Don't delete (e.g PeterT would lose the rep, others still could benefit from this),  just edit your question and add the solution to the end (include Andre's links). In addition to them maybe have a look at [Rubberduck-VBA](http://rubberduckvba.com/), an Add-In that provides many hints/tools on vba-programming. If you like it link too.